# To maintain session accross xyz.com and www.xyz.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a rails website on www.xyz.com. After I log in to www.xyz.com, if if move to xyz.com, I need to log in again, ie the session is not maintained. 
How to make www.xyz.com and xyz.com use the same session.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764509/pass-authentication-between-php-and-ruby-on-rails-application

Comment: those are 2 different applications, here they are the same application. It is also about how to do it in rails.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663893/losing-session-in-rails-2-3-2-app-using-subdomain/2709486#2709486. For Rails 2.3.5 session config is stored in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend sticking with one or the other. It's better for SEO and much easier to deal with.