# Mediawiki authentication by checking API with Ruby or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I want to see if a user is logged in to my mediawiki-application. I think a good way to solve it is to do an API-request to the mediawiki-application and check if the user is logged in. The only problem is that I have no experience at all with JSON or API:s :D.

I've looked around a little bit and found this good looking gem: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

With this gem I can check my api. An example is:

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php')
```

With this I get a bunch of useful data. The **problem** however is that this request is done on behalf of the server and not the user. I won't be able to see if the user is logged in but I can see if my server is logged in. Which I don't care for...

Any solution on how to do this api-request on behalf of the user? Perhaps in one of the views?

If I could do it like mediawiki does it would be fine: [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&meta=userinfo&format=json](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aApiSandbox#action=query&meta=userinfo&format=json)

Maybe you could do some javascript that would solve this problem...

Comment: You mean you're writing an application that runs on some domain and you want to check whether the user is logged in to a MediaWiki installation that runs on the same domain?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. It is going to be a different type of application anyhow. I'm not used to writing in php...

Comment: Did you look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764509/pass-authentication-between-php-and-ruby-on-rails-application

Comment: If your ruby app is running on the same machine, then you can check the cookie against the session file since that is what php/Mediawiki does.

Comment: I can't test that in development mode. And I'm not actually sure if I am going to use it on the same server. There are enough applications running there already...

Comment: I think there is a cookie set. If you look at the cookies set you have

Answer (score 1):

You can write a very simple [API extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aExtensions) to you MediaWiki installation, that lets you query the API to check if a certain user is logged in. Use [`User::isLoggedin`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classUser.html#ac1eeb3fabf0d0398ba60d537316c3bbe) to do the actual check.

You can use the skeleton at [https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aExtensions) , and then replace `function execute()` with something like this:

```
public function execute() {

    $userName = $this->getMain()->getVal('user');
    $user = User::newFromName($userName);

    $isLoggedIn = $user->isLoggedIn ();

    if ( $isLoggedIn ) {

        $returnValue = 'yes';

    } else {

        $returnValue = 'no';

    }

    $this->getResult()->addValue( null, $this->getModuleName(),
                                  array ( 'loggedin' => $returnValue ) );

    return true;

}
```

Now you can query the API using Ruby or Javascript (or whatever):

```
api.php?action=checkIfUserIsLoggedIn&user=AdaLovelace&format=json
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. The problem is that I don't have the user's username in the Ruby-app. That is the information I want to find out. 

Is there a way to check what user is logged in with which IP-address? In that case I could take the IP-address from my Ruby app, check it with mediawiki to see who is logged in, get the username and then have the user to be logged in :). Thanks leo

Comment: NVM. IP-address won't work. If I would use that there could only be one person per IP-address logged in :D.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies. If you look at the cookies set you have `wikiNameUserID`, `wikiNameUserName` and  `wikiName_session`. If they have logged out then `wikiNameLoggedOut` will be set and `wikiNameUserID` deleted. This will work as long as you app is on the same domain.

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Cookie_tracking for details.